# Assign object to var in each

Tags: jquery, foreach

I have a very simple jQ function, but I cannot assign the "row" to the "tablerow" var.

I dont know why :(

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-remove-entry', function() {
    var tablerow = null; 
    $.each($('.filter'), function(idx, row) {
        if($(row).hasClass('info')) {
             talberow = $(row);
             console.log(talberow);
        }
    });
    console.log(tablerow);
    if(tablerow != null) {
        $('.filter-list tr').remove(tablerow);      
    }
});
```

The Tablerow is at every time 'null'. The first console shows me the correct table row. But the Second at line 9 logs 'null' again.

Why?

---

The working result

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-remove-entry', function() {
    $.each($('.filter'), function(idx, row) {
        if($(row).hasClass('info')) {
            $(row).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `talberow` ≠ `tablerow`

Comment: Okay, we found the problem of your question. But what do you really want to do there? The code is really wired ...

Comment: Added to my question ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `tablerow` not `talberow`. And you can use the `each` with the selector directly.

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-remove-entry', function() {
    var tablerow = null;

    $('.filter').each(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass('info')) {
            tablerow = $(this);
        }
    });

    if(tablerow != null) {
        $('.filter-list tr').remove(tablerow);      
    }
});
```